# Find the longest path with A*

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I'm trying to figure out if I can use A* algorithm to fine the longest path to goal under the assumption of admissibility.

I tried with maximal `max(f(n)=g(n)+h(octile-distance))`, but it seems wrong to me.

1. If admissible heuristic is to under estimate the `f*`, for longest path i had to find heuristic that always over estimate the `f*`?
2. According to 1, if i need to over-estimate geographic distance to goal. someone can recommend me for some kind of heuristic ?
3. Is it optimal finding the longest path with A* like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the [longest path is NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), so trying to adapt A* or any other shortest path algorithm to find it will unfortunately not work.

Comment: But A* solve this restriction with admissible heuristics, no?

Comment: Which restriction? You seem to assume that shortest-path and longest-path problem are equivalent or similar in their structure but they are fundamentally different. In the shortest path problem you can build upon intermediate results (e.g., shortest paths to intermediate nodes). In the longest path problem, the longest path to an intermediate node will not tell you anything you can use about the longest path to  a destination.